# NameError: global name 'browser' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, acceptance-testing

I am using Pycharm and Pytest with Selenium Webdriver.

I have set up an Initiate driver.py with the following code:

```
    om selenium import webdriver
from Library import ConfigReader


def start_browser():
    global browser

    if (ConfigReader.read_config_data('Details', 'Browser')) =="chrome":
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

    elif (ConfigReader.read_config_data('Details', 'Browser')) =="firefox":
        browser = webdriver.Firefox('geckodriver')

    browser.get(ConfigReader.read_config_data('Details', 'Application_URL'))
    browser.maximize_window()
    return browser

def close_browser():
    browser.close()
```

When I run I get the following error:

```
def start_browser():
    global browser

    if (ConfigReader.read_config_data('Details', 'Browser')) =="chrome":
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

    elif (ConfigReader.read_config_data('Details', 'Browser')) =="firefox":
        browser = webdriver.Firefox('geckodriver')




>       browser.get(ConfigReader.read_config_data('Details', 'Application_URL'))
E       NameError: global name 'browser' is not defined
```

I set the browser as global and so I am unsure why I am getting this error

Comment: What if none of the conditionals are true?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: always try to avoid using the `global` keyword. It causes instability i code as it gets longer and complex.

Anyways, your code says global is not defined because you don't have the `global` variable named `browser` defined outside of the function scopes.

Remove the `global` keyword. You don't need it since you are returning `browser` to the function itself.

Here how it will look like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from Library import ConfigReader

def start_browser():
    if (ConfigReader.read_config_data('Details', 'Browser')) =="chrome":
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

    elif (ConfigReader.read_config_data('Details', 'Browser')) =="firefox":
        browser = webdriver.Firefox('geckodriver')

    browser.get(ConfigReader.read_config_data('Details', 'Application_URL'))
    browser.maximize_window()
    return browser

def close_browser():
    start_browser().close()
```

Comment: My test is:
from Base import InitiateDriver



def test_new():
    browser = InitiateDriver.start_browser()
    browser.close() but now I get this error: Base/InitiateDriver.py:11: UnboundLocalError